# Recreate vcvars32.bat without reinstalling Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

On my system vcvars32.bat - part of the Visual Studio 2010 installation - has suddenly disappeared. When I start a VS2010 Command Prompt, I get the following message:

> The specified configuration type is missing.  The tools for the
>   configuration might not be installed.

Needless to say I haven't removed this file, but files don't disappear by themselves either. Supposedly it is created by the Visual Studio setup, so I'm wondering:

- Has anyone else have this file disappear due to installing Visual Studio or Windows updates? If so, which update?
- Can I recreate this file without reinstalling Visual Studio 2010, SP1, some Windows Update 
  distributed hotfixes and Feature Pack 2?

Comment: No, pretty sure your case is unique.  Copy the file from a machine of a team member.  But you'd better visit superuser.com first to ask how to get some confidence back in your hard drive.

Comment: @Hans The hard drive is fine, it's just that the files in this directory (with 1 exception) are gone... I can copy the file, but supposedly it's generated on the fly based on configuration, so I wanted to avoid that. Beats reinstalling though.